# How do I get only those lines that has highest value if they are inside a timewindow?

Tags: python, rows

I am new to the python and scripting in general, so I would really appreciate some guidance in writing a python script.
So, to the point:

I have a big number of files in a directory. Some files are empty, other contain rows like that:

16 2009-09-30T20:07:59.659Z 0.05 0.27 13.559 6
16 2009-09-30T20:08:49.409Z 0.22 0.312 15.691 7
16 2009-09-30T20:12:17.409Z -0.09 0.235 11.826 4
16 2009-09-30T20:12:51.159Z 0.15 0.249 12.513 6
16 2009-09-30T20:15:57.209Z 0.16 0.234 11.776 4
16 2009-09-30T20:21:17.109Z 0.38 0.303 15.201 6
16 2009-09-30T20:23:47.959Z 0.07 0.259 13.008 5
16 2009-09-30T20:32:10.109Z 0.0 0.283 14.195 5
16 2009-09-30T20:32:10.309Z 0.0 0.239 12.009 5
16 2009-09-30T20:37:48.609Z -0.02 0.256 12.861 4
16 2009-09-30T20:44:19.359Z 0.14 0.251 12.597 4
16 2009-09-30T20:48:39.759Z 0.03 0.284 14.244 5
16 2009-09-30T20:49:36.159Z -0.07 0.278 13.98 4
16 2009-09-30T20:57:54.609Z 0.01 0.304 15.294 4
16 2009-09-30T20:59:47.759Z 0.27 0.265 13.333 4
16 2009-09-30T21:02:56.209Z 0.28 0.272 13.645 6

and so on.

I want to get this lines out of the files into a new file. But there are some conditionals!
If two or more successive lines are inside a timewindow of 6 seconds, then only the line with highest treshold should be printed into the new file.

So, something like that:

Original:
16 2009-09-30T20:32:10.109Z 0.0 0.283 14.195 5
16 2009-09-30T20:32:10.309Z 0.0 0.239 12.009 5

in output file:
16 2009-09-30T20:32:10.109Z 0.0 0.283 14.195 5

Keep in mind, that lines from different files can have times inside 6s window with lines from other files, so the line, that will be in output is the one that has highest treshold from different files.

The code that explains what is what in the lines is here:

```
import glob 
from datetime import datetime

path = './*.cat'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:  

    in_file=open(file, 'r')  
    out_file = open("times_final", "w")

    for line in in_file.readlines():
        split_line = line.strip().split(' ')
        template_number = split_line[0]
        t = datetime.strptime(split_line[1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        mag = split_line[2]
        num = split_line[3]
        threshold = float(split_line[4])
        no_detections = split_line[5]

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Thank you very much for hints, guidelines, ...

Comment: what have you tried to discard unwanted records? and are the records between files overlapping or strictly non-overlapping (1 file ends, 2nd file continues with only higher dates)?

Comment: i dont care about the unwanted records. Files are overlaping

Comment: well... it is simple to only create one file out of all this files and work with this. that should simplify the code.  So, lets say I only have one file that is time sorted?

Comment: next, how do you define the "window", e.g. for times that differ only in seconds: `01, 05, 06, 07, 08, 12, 13, 14, 20` - what would be the windows here?

Comment: timewindow is 6s. So, if there is a time difference higher then 6 seconds, line is ok, if time difference between successive lines is less then 6 sec, only the one with higher treshold is taken.

Comment: so the above example would be reduced to only 1 highest treshold even if the difference in total is 20 second, because individual differences are always <= 6s?

Comment: no, only 01, 05 and 06 are now only one, 07, 08, 12 are one, 13, 14 are one and 20 is one

Comment: so if there was 1 previous record `56, 01, 05, 06, 07, 08` than the windows will be totally different and you are ok with that?

Comment: This one should output one of 56, 01, one of 05, 06, 07, 08. So, u start with first line in the file. So everything depends on this line. If window between 1 and 2 line is more then 6s, output will be different then if time window between 1 and 2 is less then 6s. Indeed. But this is ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you said in the comments you know how to merge multiple files into 1 sorted by `t` and that the 6 second windows start with the first row and are based on actual data.

so, you need a way to remember the maximum threshold per window and write only after you are sure you processed all rows in a window. sample implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

fieldnames=("template_number", "t", "mag","num", "threshold", "no_detections")
with open('master_data') as f_in, open("times_final", "w") as f_out:
    reader = DictReader(f_in, delimiter=" ", fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer = DictWriter(f_out, delimiter=" ", fieldnames=fieldnames,
                        lineterminator="\n")
    window_start = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    window_timedelta = timedelta(seconds=6)
    window_max = 0
    window_row = None
    for row in reader:
        try:
            t = datetime.strptime(row["t"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
            threshold = float(row["threshold"])
        except ValueError:
            # replace by actual error handling
            print("Problem with: {}".format(row))    
        # switch to new window after 6 seconds
        if t - window_start > window_timedelta:
            # write out previous window before switching
            if window_row:
                writer.writerow(window_row)
            window_start = t
            window_max = threshold
            window_row = row
        # remember max threshold inside a single window
        elif threshold > window_max:
            window_max = threshold
            window_row = row
    # don't forget the last window
    if window_row:
        writer.writerow(window_row)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as planed (tested on premade data that i knew how it should look like).